# JavaFx Charts highlight entire curve on hover

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I am using a logarithmic scale for a graph and I want to be able to make the individual curves a little wider when hovered over and on top of all the other curves as well as the color key's value too. Below is a picture better illustrating what I want to do (with sensitive data redacted)

[image]

Is something like this even possible? And if so what direction should I move in to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

The first of your cases, which is applying the visual changes when the mouse hovers over the curve, is possible by modifying the `Node` that represents the `Series` on the chart, which is a `Path`. You can apply the changes to the stroke of the `Path` making it darker, wider and bringing in to the front when the mouse enters and reverting them when the mouse leaves

---

The second, which is applying the visual changes when hovering over the legend items is still possible but it's **not as clean** a solution, at least it's not in my implementation below. With a `Node` [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) you can get the items and cast them to either a `Label` or a `LegendItem` which expose the graphic and text. I chose `Label` to avoid using the internal API

See more here: [It is a bad practice to use Sun's proprietary Java classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes)

With `String` comparisons between the legend text and series names you can associate the two assuming each series has a name and that it is unique. If it isn't unique you could compare the stroke fills as well as the names

**Important:** These assumptions limit this approach and so if possible I'd avoid it

---

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
public class DarkerSeriesOnHoverExample extends Application {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //LogarithmicNumberAxis source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424519/5556314
        LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(new LogarithmicNumberAxis(1, 1000000), new NumberAxis(0, 2.25, 0.25));
        lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);

        //Values guessed from the screen shot
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> seriesData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new XYChart.Data(1, 2),
                new XYChart.Data(10, 2), new XYChart.Data(100, 2), new XYChart.Data(1000, 1.85),
                new XYChart.Data(10000, 1.50), new XYChart.Data(100000, 1.20), new XYChart.Data(1000000, 0.9));

        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> series2Data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new XYChart.Data(1, 2),
                new XYChart.Data(10, 2), new XYChart.Data(100, 2), new XYChart.Data(1000, 1.60),
                new XYChart.Data(10000, 1.25), new XYChart.Data(100000, 0.95), new XYChart.Data(1000000, 0.65));

        ObservableList<XYChart.Data> series3Data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new XYChart.Data(1, 2),
                new XYChart.Data(10, 1.85), new XYChart.Data(100, 1.55), new XYChart.Data(1000, 1),
                new XYChart.Data(10000, 0.65), new XYChart.Data(100000, 0.5), new XYChart.Data(1000000, 0.45));

        ObservableList<XYChart.Series> displayedSeries = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new XYChart.Series("Series 1", seriesData), new XYChart.Series("Series 2", series2Data),
                new XYChart.Series("Series 3", series3Data));

        lineChart.getData().addAll(displayedSeries);
        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        darkenSeriesOnHover(displayedSeries); //Setup for hovering on series (cleaner)
        darkenSeriesOnLegendHover(lineChart); //Setup both hovering on series and legend (messier)
    }

    private void darkenSeriesOnHover(List<XYChart.Series> seriesList){
        for(XYChart.Series series : seriesList){
            Node seriesNode = series.getNode();
            //seriesNode will be null if this method is called before the scene CSS has been applied
            if(seriesNode != null && seriesNode instanceof Path){
                Path seriesPath = (Path) seriesNode;
                Color initialStrokeColor = (Color)seriesPath.getStroke();
                double initialStrokeWidth = seriesPath.getStrokeWidth();

                seriesPath.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor.darker(), initialStrokeWidth*2, true);
                });
                seriesPath.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                    //Reset
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor, initialStrokeWidth, false);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void darkenSeriesOnLegendHover(LineChart lineChart){
        Set<Node> legendItems = lineChart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item");
        List<XYChart.Series> seriesList = lineChart.getData();

        //Will be empty if this method is called before the scene CSS has been applied
        if(legendItems.isEmpty()){ return; }

        for(Node legendItem : legendItems){
            Label legend = (Label) legendItem;
            XYChart.Series matchingSeries = getMatchingSeriesByName(seriesList, legend.getText());
            if(matchingSeries == null){ return; }

            Node seriesNode = matchingSeries.getNode();
            //seriesNode will be null if this method is called before the scene CSS has been applied
            if(seriesNode != null && seriesNode instanceof Path){
                Path seriesPath = (Path) seriesNode;
                Color initialStrokeColor = (Color)seriesPath.getStroke();
                double initialStrokeWidth = seriesPath.getStrokeWidth();

                legendItem.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor.darker(), initialStrokeWidth*2, true);
                });
                legendItem.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                    //Reset
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor, initialStrokeWidth, false);
                });

                seriesPath.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor.darker(), initialStrokeWidth*2, true);
                });
                seriesPath.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                    //Reset
                    updatePath(seriesPath, initialStrokeColor, initialStrokeWidth, false);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void updatePath(Path seriesPath, Paint strokeColor, double strokeWidth, boolean toFront){
        seriesPath.setStroke(strokeColor);
        seriesPath.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        if(!toFront){ return; }
        seriesPath.toFront();
    }

    private XYChart.Series getMatchingSeriesByName(List<XYChart.Series> seriesList, String searchParam){
        for (XYChart.Series series : seriesList){
            if(series.getName().equals(searchParam)){
                return series;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

Before vs Hover

[image: before hover]
[image: hover]